# How to provide a custom variance to OLS in order to estimate coefficients confidence intervals?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm using statsmodels in order to analyze some data. I determined six coefficients using OLS and I get the confidence interval that I suppose are being calculated by the library estimating the variance as ssr / df_resid.
Let's suppose I now want to provide the OLS a custom variance I estimated and make it use this in order to calculate the coefficients confidence interval. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit tricky to change attributes in the Results instances in statsmodels, because many attributes are calculated lazily and then cached. Any use of backdoors or direct assignment to attributes might result in inconsistent and incorrect results. However, since it's Python, it would be possible to change the internally stored `cov_params_default`.

One possibility to get the inference for the parameters based on a covariance matrix given by the user, is to use `t_test` which has a `cov_p` argument for providing a cov_params.

Something like

```
tt = results.t_test(np.eye(len(results.params)), cov_p = myscale * results.normalized_cov_params)
```

then `tt` contains the same information as a summary params table, see `dir(tt)` and `print(tt)`

However, since fixing the scale, error variance estimate is not an uncommon use case, it is now supported directly, in current statsmodels master and will be released with 0.7. Currently only supported for the linear regression models OLS, WLS, GLS.

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/2137

for example for WLS:

```
res = WLS(ydata, xdata, weights=weights).fit(cov_type='fixed scale', cov_kwds={'scale':2})
```